# Seeking country, region, and city data

Tags: data

I need the names of countries, country regions and cities of the world.

Where do I get that kind of information?

Answer (score 10):

Try the data provided by Natural Earth at http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Multiple datasets are provided including countries, states, populated places, urban areas etc

You can also download a database of over 8 million place names from http://www.geonames.org/ but that may be overkill for what you're looking for.

Comment: Natural Earth v2 has many hours of data cleanup improving the quality of the data throughout. Released August 2012

Answer (score 5):

**Natural Earth Version 2** [Out this week 18th August 2012]

[image]

http://kelsocartography.com/downloads/gis/2012/natural_earth/ne_2.0.0_rc2/natural_earth_2.0.0_rc2_vector/

Quick Start:
http://kelsocartography.com/downloads/gis/2012/natural_earth/ne_2.0.0_rc2/natural_earth_2.0.0_rc2_vector/Natural_Earth_quick_start_2.0.0_rc2.zip

18-Aug-2012 17:59  234M

Answer (score 3):

Give it a try to the files hosted here:

http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

> The dataset is available in shapefile
> format:
>
> TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip (3,380 kB)
>
> TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip (226
> kB)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the names, try geonames.org

http://www.geonames.org/countries/

- get you the countries. Drill down for cities, or download their datafiles for everything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [countries, regions and cities database](https://github.com/prograhammer/countries-regions-cities) database dump hosted on Github. Might be useful for MySQL users

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [naturalearth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/), that should cover your need

> Natural Earth is a public domain map dataset available at 1:10m,
>   1:50m, and 1:110 million scales. Featuring tightly integrated vector
>   and raster data, with Natural Earth you can make a variety of visually
>   pleasing, well-crafted maps with cartography or GIS software

Answer (score 0):

As a commmiter of https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/ I'd recommend using our database or at least the approach behind it. See https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/wiki

[image: Database structure of geograpy3]

The data is derived from different sources - mostly Wikidata.